# Circle hover effect to scale to fill div to 100%

Tags: css, hover, transition, geometry

hoping someone can help me with this..?

Heres my devsite:
http://colinmorley.com/stuck/index2new.html

As you will be able to see its responsive with everything except the brand spanking new circle hover effect. Its just not scaling like the other elements to fit to the width and height of the div it sits within.

I found the tutorial for the circle hover effect here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/

Basically how do i make it scale to fit and then reduce down when in a smaller browser size???

Many thanks if you can help :)

Col

Comment: Post a fiddle with the relevant resources please.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Remove the height from the `<li>` element, and add these styles to that element:

```
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
position: relative;
```

**2.** Add these styles to that `<li>` element's child `<div>`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

**4.** Replace that child `<div>`'s `:hover` state box-shadow with this:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0, 0.6), inset 0 0 0 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

**3.** Remove the top margin on the link's wrapper div (`.Col`), and add these styles:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -12px;
```

I took a screenshot of my results:

[image]